# How to call a API in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a problem with angular JS Controller function. I have a controller and in that controller I have bunch of functions which are getting called from a service which contains HTTP get and post requests.

To be specific my question is inside a controller, when I try to write:

```
$scope.functionName = function()
{
    //some code
}
```

My function doesn't get called at all. And when I do the following my function gets called but the scope goes undefined for rest of the functions.

```
app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) {
    getAll();
    getAppKey();
    getAppDefaults();

    function getAll(){//some code}
    function getAppKey(){//some code}
    function AppDefaults(){//some code
})
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I would really appreciate anyone's help who can help me out with this issue.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/B9RsQ/45/

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for getting back to me. Yes, I'm using $scope as you did in your example. Even, then my function doesn't get called. It doesn't give any error also.

Comment: You'll need to show a [mcve]. There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown in the question (other than defining `AppDefaults()` and calling `getAppDefaults()`).

Comment: Hi,I've posted my code in the folowing post can you have a glance at it.

Comment: app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) { 
$scope.getAll();
$scope.getAll = function()
{
    //some code  
 }

Comment: No, **edit the question** and put the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are defining function with $scope and calling function without $scope.
This code will work:

```js
app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) {

    $scope.getAll = function{
        console.log("function called");
    }

    $scope.getAll();
})
```

And this code will not work as expected:

```js
app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) {

    $scope.getAll = function{
        console.log("function called");
    }

    getAll();
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for getting back to me. Yes, I'm using $scope as you did in your example. Even, then my function doesn't get called. It doesn't give any error also.

Comment: Now, I get one question, So, why should we use that getAll(); in the end, does that make any difference. I apologize if this is silly question, I'm new to this angular JS.

Comment: app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) {

    $scope.getAll = function(){
        console.log("function called");
    } I'm not using that getAll(); here , So, is it because of this reason it is not working

Comment: in the above comment you define function but did not called it

Comment: where are you using getAll();

Comment: Actually I did not use GetAll() again after using $scope.getAll(){//some code}. So, where should i use getAll(). in the following way: **app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) {
getALL();
    $scope.getAll = function{
        console.log("function called");
    }**

Comment: you should use $scope.getAll() instead of getAll()

Comment: Okay! I will try it once

Comment: It is giving me following error when I use it:**Object doesn't support property or method 'getAll'**

Comment: one thing that call method after the definition of method

Comment: app.controller("ControllerName", function ($scope, ServiceName) { 

$scope.getAll = function()
{
    //some code  
 }$scope.getAll(); It says function not foud

Comment: Yup! Your suggestion worked! Thank You So much. I was spending so many hours with this issue, now it is solved, I appreciate your help

Comment: Now, i come up with another issue, scope gets undefined when I try to use it in another function which belongs to same controller.

Comment: use like this. $scope.name = "shivam". it will set name attribute in scope. then you can access $scope.name in anywhere in controller

Comment: Where should I define this? Inside a function or in the controller.

Comment: there is a lot of comment. Ask another question for different problem.

Comment: OK! I have to wait for 90 minutes

Answer (score 0):

'...bunch of functions which are getting called from a service...' ?

You can't call function from controller in service. What you can do is to use functions from service in controller.

If you want to use methods from service inside your controller, first inject service(you already did that),

then call it:

ServiceName.getAll();
ServiceName.getAppKey();
...
etc.

If you want to use this functions from controller, make another service/factory put this functions inside that service, inject service2 in service and again you can use them like:

ServiceName2.getAll();
ServiceName2.getAppKey();

Comment: Yeah I'm doing everything as you suggested the main problem is in the controller. When I use $scope.function my function doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to acomplish, maybie this?
this code works:

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert("called.........");
  }

  defaultFunction = function() {
    alert("defaultFunction called.........");
  }
  defaultFunction();
});
```

$scope is added when you want to use in view, if you need to use it in controller, no need for $scope

you can change http://jsfiddle.net/B9RsQ/45/ to test it

Comment: Thank you for the time I was not using $scope.functionName below the function that is the reason why it was not getting called. This was a silly mistake I'm new to Angular JS

Comment: Now, i come up with another issue, scope gets undefined when I try to use it in another function which belongs to same controller.

Comment: little more info?

Comment: without $scope you can't access your function in view.

Comment: Like say in a function 1 I use $scope.Name = d.table.data. Then in function 2 I want to use this $scope.name. which always say that scope is undefined